# Symfony development toolbar missing for some routes

Tags: symfony, controller, url-routing

In the process of trying to figure out Symfony I've been doing some of the walk throughs for router/controller which are all working except that one one of them I'm no longer getting the symfony toolbar in the dev environment:

**These both work and the development toolbar is present:**

- `http://localhost/app_dev.php/app/example`
- `http://localhost/app_dev.php/random/111`

**This works but the development toolbar has disappeared:**

- `http://localhost/app_dev.php/hello/world`

I'm not sure if it's related but every now and then throughout the day I'm getting an error returned (and when I resubmit, the error disappears):

```
ContextErrorException in FileProfilerStorage.php line 137:
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied`
```

---

The routing/controller for this hello world test is as follows:

**/app/config/routing.yml**:

```
acme_test2:
    resource: "@AcmeTest2Bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

app:
    resource: @AppBundle/Controller/
    type:     annotation
```

**AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController:**

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/app/example", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
    }


    /**
     * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="hello")
     */
    public function helloAction($name)
    {
        return $this->render('default/hello.html.twig', array(
            'name' => $name
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the below code from my `/app/config/routing.yml` and now the development toolbar appears on all the routes:

```
acme_test2:
    resource: "@AcmeTest2Bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

as the first line in the generated html.

Comment: Thanks Udan - I managed to get it working although I must admit I'm not entirely sure of why it works(!). I will post the answer now - hopefully someone will explain the logic of WHY it works! :oP

Answer (score 0):

I had as well issues with a missing toolbar on some of my routes - in particular those using a twig template.
This was caused by a missing `</body>` in my .twig template.

Adding `</body>` in the template solved that and the toolbar was visible again.